# IEDriverServer sending keys incredibly slowly - JavaScript Alternative Advice

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Im trying to send keys with Selenium and IEDriverServer but I've encountered a problem where the keys are getting sent to the input incredibly slowly.

I've done some research and a lot of websites suggest to make sure that the Browser and IEDriverServer are the same bit (which i have and their the same) but im still getting the keys sent slowly to the input.

I've found a solution where i can use JavaScript to set the value of the input but im not too sure if this is a good way to go about fixing the slow keys bug.

Is there any downfalls to using JavaScript instead of Selenium's sendkeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably caused by native events usage. At this point I don't properly remember the full story, but turning native events off like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

forces IEDriverServer to use JS instead of native events (those, that are used when you access use IE directly) and makes everything work a bit faster in IE tests. And I don't think there any real drawbacks to this as well.

More info [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Native_Events_and_Internet_Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

nativeEvents should work. You also look for a Javascript solution, here you can do it like:

```
webDriver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + stringValue +"')", webElement);
```

with webElement is inputField, e.g. Username, Password, etc.